# No Android option found in Eclipse 3.6.1 Helios in Windows>Preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I am currently under Android Trainee.

I first installed jdk-1.6 (64 bit) on my Windows7 OS, and set the PATH system variable upto JDK bin.

After that I installed Eclipse 3.6.2 Helios(64 bit), but now, no android option is there on left side of

> Windows>Preference

Guys please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions.  You need to:

1) Install Java (check)

2) Install Eclipse (I'd recommend Eclipse 3.7 Indigo)

3) Install the Android SDK

4) Configure Android in Eclipse

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html